# TextTrimming property of a textblock not working

Tags: windows-phone-7, textblock, texttrimming

I can find a property called TextTrimming for `TextBlock`, but I can't get it working.
I have a text block in the MainPage, which is intended to give a preview.. When i click a button if there is any notes saved in it, I need to display few characters.

Even when I have set the TextTrimming propery, the whole text is being shown. I tried reducing the width of the textblock but it still displays the text strechin the whole screen

This is the xaml code

```
<TextBlock 
     Height="27" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     x:Name="notesPreview" 
     Text="" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" 
     Width="236" 
     Foreground="Gray" 
     Canvas.Left="20" 
     Canvas.Top="526" 
     TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
     MinWidth="236" />
```

I assign the text to the textblock in the code behind like this

```
if (m_bufferArrayNotes[i, j] != "")
{
    notes = m_bufferArrayNotes[i, j].Substring(0);
}
else
{
    notes = "";
}

notesPreview.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.WordEllipsis;
notesPreview.Text = notes;
```

The size of the textblock expands and displays whole text and can be seen while pannin to the next pivot item :(.

Is there any way to keep the actual width static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this discussion on the AppHub forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/17e3d12c-c095-492d-8241-96138160501b/).

They suggest using [this custom implementation](http://blog.nerdplusart.com/archives/texttrimming-textblock-for-silverlight) to get support for TextTrimming.